Is it permissible to do puja with stolen flowers from other people's gardens?
Is doing puja with stolen flowers from other people's gardens permissible?
The question might sound silly, but it is a genuine issue in the place I stay. In the early morning, people collect flowers for puja from the gardens in the locality. They even steal flowers without telling the owner.
If you try to stop them, they get angry and say how dare you to stop us collecting flowers for Puja. Their point is by stopping them I am committing a sin.
I personally feel that doing Puja with stolen flowers should not be the rule. I was wondering whether Shastras said anything on this issue.

I would need to check regarding the offering of stolen flowers to devas. But stealing flowers in itself is labelled as a pāpa in śāstras. For e.g. Śiva Purāṇa (5.6.46-49). Since their stealing is itself said to be a pāpa, then offering stolen flowers isn’t a proper option in the first place, according to me. On a side note, I don’t think that you should stop someone who takes permission from you to pluck flowers for pūjā, that is problematic on your end surely, according to me.

@Bingming Thanks. You may write it as an answer. I will accept it.
